# TikZ: repeat a certain step between all other foreach-steps

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have a (long) list,  say `\def\List{0, 4, 7, 11, 2, 3}`. 
I draw an animation with a foreach-loopfor that (this is a very small part of a very large `tikzpicture`):

[image]

But I would like to repeat the picture for "0" (that is the black filled one) after each number.
Like as the list would look like `0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 11, 0, 2, 3, 0`.

Is there maybe a trick to get that?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\List{0, 4, 7, 11, 2, 3}

\begin{document}
\foreach \No in \List {%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\pgfmathsetmacro\Fill{\No==0 ? "black" : "none"}
\node[draw, minimum size=10mm, name=ListEntry, fill=\Fill]{\No};
\node[anchor=west] at (ListEntry.east){Situation: \No};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a second, inner loop. Fill it {\No, 0} .

Comment: Ah, yes. I think that's mostly elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a second tikzpicture inside the loop:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\List{4, 7, 11, 2, 3}

\begin{document}
\foreach \No in \List {%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[draw, minimum size=10mm, name=ListEntry, fill=black]{0};
\node[anchor=west] at (ListEntry.east){Situation: 0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[draw, minimum size=10mm, name=ListEntry]{\No};
\node[anchor=west] at (ListEntry.east){Situation: \No};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can add a nested loop:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\List{4, 7, 11, 2, 3}

\begin{document}
\foreach \No in \List {%%
\foreach \B[evaluate=\B as \k using {int(\No*\B)}] in {0,1}{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\pgfmathsetmacro\Fill{\B==0 ? "black" : "none"}
\node[draw, minimum size=10mm, name=ListEntry, fill=\Fill]{\k};
\node[anchor=west] at (ListEntry.east){Situation: \k};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx. But I think a second counter would be better, so I do not have to repeat the (long) tikzpicture-code. ;)

Comment: @cis: I updated my answer.